# Bootstrap 4 video, iframe tag not showing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, bootstrap-4

I have a Drupal site that uses a bootstrap 4 theme. I have a bootstrap card that I'm trying to add a video in it. Here is my code:

```
<div class="card">  
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Some text here about the video.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I save the page and and inspect element, the `iframe` is always missing, so the code looks like this:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

</div>
```

I tried embedding outside of the card, same issue. I know tried just using the `iFrame` without any parent divs and the iFrame code is nowhere to be found in inspect element. I'm not sure if the iFrame tag being stripped is happening on Drupal's side or not. My question is there any other way to embed a youtube/vimeo video responsively without using iFrame

Comment: Your markup works as expected in jsfiddle's bootstrap boilerplate.

Comment: @ArleighHix yea I'm thinking it's something to do with Drupal maybe or the fact it's in a Drupal view. Any idea how I can accomplish this without iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine i tried it and its working fine i think you mess calling bootstrap files or something
[image]